# What is the right way to install pipewire in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, google-chrome, wayland

As you know full-screen sharing is a missing option in Ubuntu Wayland session. I was going to join an online competition through google meet. Although you can share individual windows but not the entire screen. After searching for possible solutions I came across `pipewire`(I really don't know what it's).

I used their official manual to build it from source but there were no pages about its dependencies so I used `apt-get install "dependency-name"*` to install the available packages contain for each cmake dependency error dependency. By that, I got a lot of garbage packages installed in my system. But after installation, it was not working with Chrome (after enabling webrtc-pipewire flag) or Firefox. After struggling one hour I removed all installed files and packages from my system. I also tried it with Ubuntu's official pipewire packages(which was of an older version)

```
sudo apt install pipewire gstreamer1.0-pipewire libpipewire-0.2-1 libpipewire-0.2-dev libpipewire-0.2-doc
```

It made google meet not joining the conference. I also checked [this manual](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/pipewire.html) and failed. I installed each of it's missing dependencies and failed.

What is the proper way to install pipewire on my Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: It is available via APT from [universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pipewire&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all). You do not need to compile it. Why do you not want to simply switch back to Xorg?

Comment: In a fresh installation, it is smooth and nice. But after installing packages and customizing gnome it lags so much. I also tried installing these packages from apt repository but after installation in breaks google meet.

Comment: Pipewire support for desktop sharing is not really ready yet.
A number of dependencies need to be rebuilt to enable pipewire, these include mutter, xdg-desktop-portal and gnome-remote-desktop.
Once pipewire makes it into main [Pipewire MIR](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1802533) these other packages can be rebuilt with pipewire support